# Using relations to solve an ode.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

so I have question which reads "use the following relations $ y \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{dy^2}{dx},\ \frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d \ln y}{dx}$ to integrate

$$
\frac{1}{v}(v^2-a^2)\frac{dv}{dr} = 2\frac{a^2}{r}
$$

Aside from performing the normal U-substituion I can't see a way to do this by using them relations.

Comment: I first suggest you develop the product in your left hand term and see if you can solve it then!

Comment: Ah, okay so I'll have $ (v-\frac{a^2}{v}) \frac{dv}{dr}$?

Comment: Yes, do you see how to apply the formulas you are given, now?
By the way, I think the second you give should be $\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d(lny)}{dx}$, not $\frac{1}{y} = \frac{d(lny)}{dx}$.

Comment: Hi yes, I've done some simplification and ended up with $\frac{d}{dr}\left[ \frac{v^2}{2}-a^2\ln(v)\right]$

Comment: And do you know how to integrate this easily?

Comment: I'm a bit confused since the solution is listed as
$$
\frac{v^2}{a^2} -ln(\frac{v^2}{a^2})
$$

Comment: Do you have a right hand term? Because if you are asked to integrate an equation, the result should still be an equation.